# React-native camera roll linking issue

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to add library to my project @react-native-community/cameraroll. But it is not getting linked and build always fails in Xcode, not even displaying error.

My motto is to save images to cameraroll in iOS as well as android using react-native

I am using React-native version 0.60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow steps:

```
react-native unlink  @react-native-community/cameraroll
npm uninstall @react-native-community/cameraroll
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package-lock.json
npm install
npm install @react-native-community/cameraroll --save
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
react-native run-ios
```

if this does not work for any reason just uninstall  @react-native-community/cameraroll library and then try to run using react-native run-ios app command and check if this works then add following to your package.json file under dependencies:

```
"@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.2.1"
```

Its working for me.

Comment: great to hear that it helped you.